# Setting Heroku to accept traffic only from CloudFlare

Tags: heroku, cloudflare

I have a website deployed on `Heroku` (e.g. www.example.com) and I have set up `CloudFlare` to work as my `CDN`, therefore all traffic to my website goes through CloudFlare.

But I still have the link to my app on `Heroku` sub-domain (example.heroku.com), and if somebody tries this address, it wouldn't pass through `CloudFlare` anymore.

How can I hide my Heroku app address (example.heroku.com) and make my website to accept traffic only from CloudFlare?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on the assumption that you're using Heroku to host a Ruby Rack application, since I believe that is the profile of most of Heroku's users. Otherwise, please skip.

If you're hosting a Rack app on Heroku, you could potentially insert a small piece of Rack middleware to do redirects for you.

```
# lib/rack/domain_redirect.rb
# encoding utf-8

# Rack Middleware that was created to handle
# autoredirecting requests away from *.herokuapp.com to
# the equivalent *.example.com. That said, it does allow you to configure
# what domain to redirect from and what domain to redirect to as well
module Rack
  class DomainRedirect

    attr_accessor :redirect_from_domain, :redirect_to_domain

    def initialize(app, redirect_from_domain = "herokuapp.com", redirect_to_domain = "example.com")
      self.redirect_from_domain = redirect_from_domain
      self.redirect_to_domain = redirect_to_domain
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      if request.host.include?(redirect_from_domain)
        [301, {"Location" => request.url.sub(redirect_from_domain, redirect_to_domain)}, []]
      else
        @app.call(env)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Then in your config.ru

```
# some other middlewares and requires

require File.expand_path("../lib/rack/domain_redirect.rb", __FILE__)
use Rack::DomainRedirect

# run your app
run MyApp
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm actually using Node.js, but I can use the same redirection idea. I preferred to avoid it altogether by completely hiding behind CloudFlare.